# deserializing a JSON object with multiple items inside it

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to deserialize (using gson) a JSON object that looks like this:

```
        "attachments": {
            "40": {
                "ID": 40,
                "URL": "http:\/\/drewmore4.files.wordpress.com\/2013\/02\/wreckit.jpg",
                "guid": "http:\/\/drewmore4.files.wordpress.com\/2013\/02\/wreckit.jpg",
                "mime_type": "image\/jpeg",
                "width": 287,
                "height": 400
            },
            "3": {
                "ID": 3,
                "URL": "http:\/\/drewmore4.files.wordpress.com\/2013\/02\/frankenweenie2bposter.jpg",
                "guid": "http:\/\/drewmore4.files.wordpress.com\/2013\/02\/frankenweenie2bposter.jpg",
                "mime_type": "image\/jpeg",
                "width": 273,
                "height": 400
            }
    },
```

How do I handle it? I don't even know what to call this - There are multiple "items" represented here, but it's not an array. When I try to deserialize it as an array, the program crashes on a "Expected Begin_Array but found Begin_Object" exception. When I try to deserialize it as a Strong object (see class below), the program runs but the fields all return null.

Here is the class I've tried to map it to:

```
class Attachment {
int ID;
String URL;
}
```

the full JSON file can be seen  [here:](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/drewmore4.wordpress.com/posts/?pretty=1)

EDIT: SOLVED.

@Perception's solution basically worked. It was complicated by the fact that this "element" (still would like to know what this multiple-entry/non-array json element) is embedded in a larger json object that does contain an array. Again, this JSON is not my design - it comes from the Wordpress REST API, and (as @Perception alluded to), I think the issue I've had illustrates a design flaw in it - namely that the attachments element should be an array, rather than a single object. Nonetheless,

Nonetheless, if anyone else ever needs to deserialize the result of a query for all posts on a given site using this API, and further needs access to the attachments on each post, here's how you do it:

```
  private class getAll extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, JSONObject> {
    private static final String url = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/drewmore4.wordpress.com/posts/";
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
        JSONObject returned = new JSONObject();
        HttpResponse response;

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);

                returned =new JSONObject(result);                   
                instream.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException | IOException | JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace();} 

        return returned;
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (JSONObject returned){
        Gson gson = new Gson();

//posts is the element within the JSONObject that is an array of post objects
        try {
        JSONArray posts = returned.getJSONArray("posts");

        for (int curr = 0; curr < posts.length(); curr++){
            String s = posts.get(curr).toString();

            Article a = gson.fromJson(s, Article.class);

            JSONObject attachments = new JSONObject(s).getJSONObject("attachments");
            final Iterator<String> keys = attachments.keys();
               while(keys.hasNext()) {
                    final String key = keys.next();
                    a.attached.add(gson.fromJson(attachments.getJSONObject(key).toString(), Attachment.class));
                }   
               stories.add(a);
        }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example of data that probably ***should*** have been serialized as an array, but was not. One solution to parsing it is to utilize a `JSONObject` directly.

```
String json = ...;
final Gson gson = new Gson();

final List<Attachment> attachements = new ArrayList<Attachment>(64);
final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("attachments");
final Iterator<String> keys = jsonObj.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
    final String key = keys.next();
    attachements.add(gson.fromJson(jsonObj.getJSONObject(key).toString(), Attachment.class);
}

// Do something with attachements
```

---

The data ***can*** also be viewed as a map, of id's to attachments. And it can be deserialized as such:

```
final String jsonObj = new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("attachments");
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final Map<String, Attachment> data = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.toString(),
        new TypeToken<Map<String, Attachment>>() {
        }.getType());
final List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<Attachment>(data.values());
```

This is actuall

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here, either on my part or yours. What is being represented here are not articles, but components of articles (namely attachments) which I'm trying to deserialize into fields of the Article instances you helped me with before..

Comment: @drewmore4 - indeed. Check out my edit (nothing substantial, basically replace `Article` with `Attachment`).

Comment: That's what I figured :) I'm trying what you suggested but am getting an error warning - Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable - on the for loop.

Comment: @drewmore4 - edited. You might have to tweak the code, I don't have access to an IDE atm.

Comment: thanks. had to do a little extra work, but your solution got me there. see my edit if you're curious

Answer (score 2):

First create JSONArray from this JSONObject.,
then

```
for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
```

By using this loop get the string values and put in a map or object that u want and add it to a ArrayList

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
```

And

```
contactList.add(map);
```

then you can use that values.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I handle it? I don't even know what to call this - There are multiple "items" represented here, but it's not an array.

It looks like the collection in the JSON is a natural fit for a `java.util.map`.  So, I'd probably deserialize the JSON "attachments" into a `Map<String, Atachment>`.  The map is then easy to iterate over, or transform the collection of Attachment values into a different type of collection, like a `List<Attachment>` or an `Attachment[]`.

Note: [The Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) includes an example of deserializing into a Generic Collection.