# Deserialize embeded Json fields objects into Java map

Tags: java, json, serialization, dictionary, gson

This is related to [deserializing a JSON object with multiple items inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060514/deserializing-a-json-object-with-multiple-items-inside-it) .

I have the following Json object I need to deserialize in Java using Gson, and for the life of me, I'm pulling my hair out.

```
 {
   "Success":1, 
    "return":
         {"MyObjects":
               {"Obj1":
                   {"Prop1":"widgets", "Label":"Obj1", "prop2":"gadgets"}}
               {"Obj2":
                   {"Prop1":"widgets2", "Label":"Obj2","prop2":"gadgets2"}}
               {"Obj3":
                   {"Prop1":"widgets3", "Label":"Obj3","prop2":"gadgets3"}}
 }
```

I have read and re-read the above linked question, and I am not quite understanding his solution.

I can make a MyJsonObject class as follows:

```
public class MyJasonObject{
    private int success;
    @SerializedName("return")
    private isReturn isreturn;
 }
```

The 'isReturn' class is where I'm lost.  How should I parse the "MyObjects" into a map or a Json object?  I didn't write the json string, it was handed to me...  It looks like I could use a map for Myobject using the label field.  But, I honestly don't know how to.

Comment: You need to read and learn the JSON format. What type is `return`? What type is `MyObjects`? What type are `Obj1`, `Obj2`, and `Obj3`?

Comment: the string I have to parse is as follows:
{"Success":1,"return":{"Myobjects":{"Obj1":{"Prop1":"widgets", "Label":"Obj1", "Prop2":"gadgets"}},{"Obj2":{"Prop1":"widgets2", "Label":"Obj2","Prop2":"gadgets2"}}}}

I'm being intentionally vague to help future users with this sort of problem.

But, to better get at your question;  I'm trying to 'type' obj1-3, which are embeded in return=>myobjects

Comment: My question was rhetorical. It doesn't matter what you are trying to get if you don't know semantically what it means. Gson maps JSON types  very well to corresponding Java types. Understand the JSON types and you'll understand what they should be mapped to.

Comment: I know JSON data types, the issue is that the serialized string is coming as a map of objects embeded in an object which is embedded in another object which is embedded in another object.  In an ideal world, it would be a nice sweet JSON Array of JSON Objects.